# alternative for the word stumble

Tags: word-choice

Somebody has checked my LinkedIn profile: I want to send him a message. I have found the following sentence on the web to start my message with

I noticed that you had stumbled upon my profile....

The word **stumble** looks a bit formal to me.

Is there any alternative for that?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, "**stumbled upon**" is *less* formal and "**come across**" is *more* formal.

**Other variations:**

> ...**happened upon** your profile.
>
> ...**chanced upon**...
>
> ...**discovered**...
>
> ...**noticed**...
>
> ...**bumped into**...

[image: Google NGram]

The phrase "**stumble upon**" has become more popular in recent years because of [a site & app by the same name](https://www.stumbleupon.com/stumbler/ashleedawg), which is for **discovering**/"stumbling onto" semi-random websites (and maybe for learning English!) :

[image: StumbleUpon.com]

Answer (score 2):

In this case, simply "found" would also work. Or "came upon".

By the way, I agree with ashleedawg that "stumble upon" is not formal at all.